# Problems with changing the date & time format in objective c xcode

Tags: objective-c, date, time, datepicker, nsdate

I've been at this for a while, browsing all the forums for help, but I just can't get this to work. I'm new to xcode and i'm trying to change yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss +0000 into e.g 21st March 2014, 6:30pm. My current code is:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];

[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[_postTime setInputView:datePicker];
}

-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender{
if([_postTime isFirstResponder]){
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)_postTime.inputView;
    _postTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",picker.date];
}
}
```

I'd appreciate all the help I can get.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NSDateFormatter` with a `dateFormat` string. If you want that yyyy-mm-dd format, use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z` (note the capital `MM` for month and `HH` for hour):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
_postTime.text = [formatter stringFromDate:picker.date];
```

If you want that 21st March 2014, 6:30pm format in your local timezone, you can use something like:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"d MMMM yyyy, hh:mma";
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
_postTime.text = [formatter stringFromDate:picker.date];
```

If you want to format that date in the format specified by the user's device (which is a nice way to present date/time, respectful of the user's preferences in settings):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
_postTime.text = [formatter stringFromDate:picker.date];
```

Refer to the [NSDateFormatter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or the [Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) section of the *Data Formatting Guide* for more information. The date formatter gives you a great deal of control over how you want the date formatted.

Comment: Rob Is it possible changing the date and time format in datePicker?. I tried lot of ways but I have not achieved.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I'd suggest you post a question, showing us what your tried and describe what precisely you need/want.